# Changing background color of unused area (not cell background) on DataGrid control

Tags: datagrid, vb6

The `BackColor` property only applies to the background of the cell area - the unused area around that (if cells do not fill the control) seems to default to Button Face.

Is there any way to set this directly?  Or make the unused area transparent to the form/container beneath it?

Answer (score 0):

use the BackColorBkg property instead

Comment: That property applies to the FlexGrid, not the DataGrid.